# Unable start the server in debug mode: hybrisserver.bat

Tags: java, e-commerce, server, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to start hybris server from console using **hybrisserver.bat debug**
but fail

This is the stack trace

> C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform>hybrisserver.bat debug 'findstr' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. Usage:
>   "C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat\bin\wrapper.bat"  { console
>   : start : pause : resume : stop : restart : install : remove : update
>   } You can give _YWRAPPER_CONF as env. variable to set the path of the
>   used wrapper  configuration file. Defaults to '..\conf\wrapper.conf'.
>   C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\platform>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me is, I copied **findstr.exe** from c:/windows/system32 and pasted it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin

or you can also try changing/appending system path variable, It should work in that case too.

Answer (score -1):

To start Hybris in Debug Mode …. 
go to Eclipse and place the Debug Breakpoints Wherever you want.
Select Extension and go on following option.
Select   “Debug   Configurations”.
Double click on  Remote Java Application.
Hybris is ready to debug. 
Debugger will Detect The Breakpoints.